# How to show message body using variable in AlertController - Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have the following code in:

**home.html**

```
<button (click)="doAlert()" color="primary" ion-button small round>
    <div><span float-right> {{ meetingTimes.meeting1 }} </span></div>
</button>
```

**home.ts**

```
doAlert() {
  let meetingTime = this.alerCtrl.create({
    title: 'Weekly Meeting Times',
    message: 'Meeting 1 time:' {{ meetingTimes.meeting1 }},
    buttons: ['Close']
  });
  meetingTime.present()
}
```

In `home.html` the `{{ meetingTimes.meeting1 }}` works fine but how do I show/use the same value in the doAlert method when clicked?

I understand that I can't use this `{{ meetingTimes.meeting1 }}` in the component but what's the correct way to do this?

I have tried : `message: 'Meeting 1 time:' + meetingTimes.meeting1,` but that didn't work.

Comment: Try to use message: `'Meeting 1 time:' + this.meetingTimes.meeting1`

Comment: Thank you so much! I need to show multiple times for different meetings. Therefore, is there another way to do this so the message body can be loaded from another page perhaps where I can add CSS to represent the message clearly?. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `ModalContoller`. You can open another page as modal dialog from `home.html`. Let's get that page is `modal.html`.

**modal.html**

```
<div id="container">
  <ion-content padding>
    <p class="message">{{message}}</p>
    <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="close()">OK</button>
  </ion-content>
</div>
```

**modal.scss**

```
#container {
  margin: 100px 50px;
  height: 120px;
  box-shadow: -3px -4px 12px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

button {
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.message {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

**ModalPage.ts**

```
export class ModalPage {

  message: string;

  constructor(
    private viewCtrl: ViewController, 
    private navParams: NavParams) {

    this.message = this.navParams.get('message');

  }
  close() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }
}
```

Now you can open **modal.html** as a Dialog from your **home.html** as below.

```
export class HomePage {

  constructor(private modalCtrl: ModalController) {}

  doAlert()() {
    let myModal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPage, { message: `Meeting 1 time: ${this.meetingTimes.meeting1}`});
    myModal.present();
  }
}
```

I think this will help you.
Find working demo [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-dbefuf?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)

Comment: Your example and the demo link was very helpful. However, when opening the modal I get an error message `Cannot read property 'meeting1' of undefined` but `{{meetingTimes.meeting1}}` works fine in home.html page.

Comment: you need to pass it correctly to modal. if you can reproduce your issue in stackblitz like my demos. i can give you the solution. but I think you got the correct answer what you ask. therefore mark this as the correct answer. it is better if you can ask `Cannot read property 'meeting1' of undefined but {{meetingTimes.meeting1}}` as a seperate question because it is not what you ask from your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
  doAlert() {
  let meetingTime = this.alerCtrl.create({
    title: 'Weekly Meeting Times',
    message: `Meeting 1 time: ${this.meetingTimes.meeting1}`,
    buttons: ['Close']
  });
  meetingTime.present()
}
```

Working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-nhbzrc?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts).

Comment: Thank you, this solution also works. Is there another way to do this so the message body can be loaded from another page perhaps where I can add CSS to represent the message in the alert more clearly?

Comment: No it is not possible with `AlertContoller`. If you need it you have to `ModalController `